# Lightweight Localhost File Server for Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, fileserver

Is there a super lightweight file server that I could use for development on my mac?

I'm imagining something like:

```
> cd somefolder
> run server
  ...running static file server at http://0.0.0.0:2343...
```

It's only for development of static html/css/js/images - no outside connections needed.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sure! And it's already installed.

Just try this:

```
cd path/to/files
python3 -m http.server
```

If you want to run it on a specific port instead of 8000 (the default), just append the port number as a second argument, like:

```
python3 -m http.server 2343
```

Comment: Nice, but be sure to enter the IPAddress:8000 I was trying with localhost and 127.0.0.1 but it didn't work

Comment: to run on port 80, if you need to: first `su`, then `python -mSimpleHTTPServer 80` . Thanks for this awesome find, clee!

Comment: Damn that's satisfying.  Perfect for deving an Angular app locally.

Comment: Works great! For me it needs to be run with `sudo`: `sudo python -mSimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: This is a great solution for dealing with cross-origin issues arising from developing locally.

Comment: Classic answer ever! :) (7 years later)

Comment: I forgot about this answer, but when I saw it, I knew it was time to port it to Python 3. Just like you should all be doing with your code by now!

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the great tip!

Comment: Be aware that by default it listens on all interfaces which is a **security risk as it exposes your files on the attached network** - add `--bind localhost` to listen only on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible using `php` (e.g. listening on localhost and port 8080):

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Or see this [question doing it with netcat/nc/bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat).