# Minimal web server using netcat

Tags: bash, webserver, netcat

I'm trying to set up a minimal web server using netcat (nc). When the browser calls up localhost:1500, for instance, it should show the result of a function (*date* in the example below, but eventually it'll be a python or c program that yields some data).
My little netcat web server needs to be a while true loop in bash, possibly as simple as this:

```
while true ; do  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l -p 1500  ; done
```

When I try this the browser shows the currently available data during the moment when nc starts. I want the browser displays the data during the moment the browser requests it, though. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks everybody for the suggestions which lead me to some more googling. As it happened I came across a completely different solution at [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsEchoServer). I can't use python or C, but I already tested it on all my target platforms. The trouble with netcat is that there are so many different versions around. Some of them don't allow -e, -c or -q options.

Comment: Note that `nc` will send the response as soon as the connection is established, which won't always be before the client sends the HTTP GET request. For many clients like Chrome and Firefox this doesn't seem to be an issue, but for at least Safari this is treated as an error and no request gets made

Answer (score 90):

Try this:

```
while true ; do nc -l -p 1500 -c 'echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)"'; done
```

The `-c`makes netcat execute the given command in a shell, so you can use echo. If you don't need echo, use `-e`. For further information on this, try `man nc`. Note, that when using `echo` there is no way for your program (the `date`-replacement) to get the browser request. So you probably finally want to do something like this:

```
while true ; do nc -l -p 1500 -e /path/to/yourprogram ; done
```

Where `yourprogram` must do the protocol stuff like handling GET, sending HTTP 200 etc.

Comment: OpenBSD netcat works different, you can do something like
`while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l localhost 1500; done`

Comment: From [man for nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc), -p description: `It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option`

Comment: The -l -p combination comes from the question and seems to work for the author of the question. So I didn't question it, but used it.

Comment: Although the nc manpage I see also says using the `-p` option together with the `-l` one is an error, the official netcat website uses both options in its examples.  See: http://nc110.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Be careful - setting stuff to varables without handling it properly can be dangerous: $something="$(shutdown)" = bad

Comment: There are at least 3 major “flavors” of `nc`: [Hobbit](http://nc110.sf.net) (the original), [BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/nc.1) / [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nc.1.html), and [GNU](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (the oldest of the bunch, and no longer maintained). There’s also Nmap’s [Ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/). I bring this up because I think it’s worth noting that the `-l` and `-p` flags together are only considered an error in the *BSD flavor* of nc, hence the alternate syntax given by @matlehmann

Comment: `-c` doesn' always work. You might need `-q` or `-w`, depending on your version/flavour. cf. https://serverfault.com/a/880289/306802

Comment: To kill the process, ctrl-C didn't work. I had to suspend (with ctrl-Z) and then `killall nc`. That seems weird. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 48):

I had the problem where I wanted to return the result of executing a bash command:

```
$ while true; do { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; sh test; } | nc -l 8080; done
```

**NOTE:**
This command was taken from: [http://www.razvantudorica.com/08/web-server-in-one-line-of-bash](https://web.archive.org/web/20130817001428/http://www.razvantudorica.com/08/web-server-in-one-line-of-bash/)

This executes a bash script and returns the result to a browser client connecting to the server running this command on port 8080.

My script does this:

```
$ nano test

#!/bin/bash

echo "************PRINT SOME TEXT***************\n"
echo "Hello World!!!"
echo "\n"

echo "Resources:"
vmstat -S M
echo "\n"

echo "Addresses:"
echo "$(ifconfig)"
echo "\n"


echo "$(gpio readall)"
```

and my web browser is showing

```
************PRINT SOME TEXT***************

Hello World!!!


Resources:
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0    314     18     78    0    0     2     1  306   31  0  0 100  0


Addresses:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:86:e8:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.83  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1924720 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:3841998 (3.6 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


GPIOs:
+----------+-Rev2-+------+--------+------+-------+
| wiringPi | GPIO | Phys | Name   | Mode | Value |
+----------+------+------+--------+------+-------+
|      0   |  17  |  11  | GPIO 0 | IN   | Low   |
|      1   |  18  |  12  | GPIO 1 | IN   | Low   |
|      2   |  27  |  13  | GPIO 2 | IN   | Low   |
|      3   |  22  |  15  | GPIO 3 | IN   | Low   |
|      4   |  23  |  16  | GPIO 4 | IN   | Low   |
|      5   |  24  |  18  | GPIO 5 | IN   | Low   |
|      6   |  25  |  22  | GPIO 6 | IN   | Low   |
|      7   |   4  |   7  | GPIO 7 | IN   | Low   |
|      8   |   2  |   3  | SDA    | IN   | High  |
|      9   |   3  |   5  | SCL    | IN   | High  |
|     10   |   8  |  24  | CE0    | IN   | Low   |
|     11   |   7  |  26  | CE1    | IN   | Low   |
|     12   |  10  |  19  | MOSI   | IN   | Low   |
|     13   |   9  |  21  | MISO   | IN   | Low   |
|     14   |  11  |  23  | SCLK   | IN   | Low   |
|     15   |  14  |   8  | TxD    | ALT0 | High  |
|     16   |  15  |  10  | RxD    | ALT0 | High  |
|     17   |  28  |   3  | GPIO 8 | ALT2 | Low   |
|     18   |  29  |   4  | GPIO 9 | ALT2 | Low   |
|     19   |  30  |   5  | GPIO10 | ALT2 | Low   |
|     20   |  31  |   6  | GPIO11 | ALT2 | Low   |
+----------+------+------+--------+------+-------+
```

Comment: better do http 1.0  because http 1.1  just adding connection: keep-alive that is bad in this case.

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin That would be pointless, since netcat doesn't understand HTTP. You activate keep-alive in netcat by passing the `-k` flag, not by adding `Connection: keep-alive` to the request header.

Comment: Works on the weird nc version on the Mac as well :)

Answer (score 43):

Add `-q 1` to the `netcat` command line:

```
while true; do 
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l -p 1500 -q 1
done
```

Comment: `-q` 1 is not working in `CentOS` 6.x what should be used for `CentOS` 6.x where it saying: `nc: invalid option -- 'q'`. `while true; do tail -f /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | nc -l 9999; done &`

Comment: @YumYumYum I'm on OS X and do not have freeswitch. What are the contents of `/usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log`?

Comment: Adding `-q 1` worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of use `-q 1` I suggest to use `-N`, like: `while true; do (echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' ; echo -e "$(date)") | nc -lN 1234 ; done` The reason is 'cause `-q` doesn't show the `HTTP Request` in the shell if this is something that you want of course.

Comment: In Alpine Linux, `cn` command doesn't have `-q`. It works as expected without it.

Answer (score 24):

The problem you are facing is that nc does not know when the web client is done with its request so it can respond to the request.
A web session should go something like this.

```
TCP session is established.
Browser Request Header: GET / HTTP/1.1
Browser Request Header: Host: www.google.com
Browser Request Header: \n #Note: Browser is telling Webserver that the request header is complete.
Server Response Header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server Response Header: Content-Type: text/html
Server Response Header: Content-Length: 24
Server Response Header: \n #Note: Webserver is telling browser that response header is complete 
Server Message Body: <html>sample html</html>
Server Message Body: \n #Note: Webserver is telling the browser that the requested resource is finished. 
The server closes the TCP session.
```

Lines that begin with "\n" are simply empty lines without even a space and contain nothing more than a new line character.

I have my bash httpd launched by xinetd, [xinetd tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4490?page=0,0%20xinetd%20turtorial). It also  logs date, time, browser IP address, and the entire browser request to a log file, and calculates Content-Length for the Server header response.

```
user@machine:/usr/local/bin# cat ./bash_httpd
#!/bin/bash
x=0;
Log=$( echo -n "["$(date "+%F %T %Z")"] $REMOTE_HOST ")$(
        while read I[$x] && [ ${#I[$x]} -gt 1 ];do
              echo -n '"'${I[$x]} | sed -e's,.$,",'; let "x = $x + 1";
        done ;
); echo $Log >> /var/log/bash_httpd

Message_Body=$(echo -en '<html>Sample html</html>')
echo -en "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: ${#Message_Body}\n\n$Message_Body"
```

To add more functionality, you could incorporate.

```
            METHOD=$(echo ${I[0]} |cut -d" " -f1)
            REQUEST=$(echo ${I[0]} |cut -d" " -f2)
            HTTP_VERSION=$(echo ${I[0]} |cut -d" " -f3)
            If METHOD = "GET" ]; then 
                case "$REQUEST" in

                    "/") Message_Body="HTML formatted home page stuff"
                        ;;
                    /who) Message_Body="HTML formatted results of who"
                        ;;
                    /ps) Message_Body="HTML formatted results of ps"
                        ;;
                    *) Message_Body= "Error Page not found header and content"
                       ;;
                esac

            fi
```

Happy bashing!

Comment: This should be accepted as solution

Answer (score 20):

Another way to do this

```
while true; do (echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; echo -e "\n\tMy website has date function" ; echo -e "\t$(date)\n") | nc -lp 8080; done
```

Let's test it with 2 HTTP request using curl

In this example, 172.16.2.6 is the server IP Address.

**Server Side**

```
admin@server:~$ while true; do (echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; echo -e "\n\tMy website has date function" ; echo -e "\t$(date)\n") | nc -lp 8080; done

GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 172.16.2.6:8080 User-Agent: curl/7.48.0 Accept:
*/*

GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 172.16.2.6:8080 User-Agent: curl/7.48.0 Accept:
*/*
```

**Client Side**

```
user@client:~$ curl 172.16.2.6:8080

        My website has date function
        Tue Jun 13 18:00:19 UTC 2017

user@client:~$ curl 172.16.2.6:8080

        My website has date function
        Tue Jun 13 18:00:24 UTC 2017

user@client:~$
```

If you want to execute another command, feel free to replace $(date).

Answer (score 15):

I had the same need/problem but nothing here worked for me (or I didn't understand everything), so this is my solution.

I post my minimal_http_server.sh (working with my /bin/bash (4.3.11) but not /bin/sh because of the redirection):

```
rm -f out
mkfifo out
trap "rm -f out" EXIT
while true
do
  cat out | nc -l 1500 > >( # parse the netcat output, to build the answer redirected to the pipe "out".
    export REQUEST=
    while read -r line
    do
      line=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r\n')

      if echo "$line" | grep -qE '^GET /' # if line starts with "GET /"
      then
        REQUEST=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f2) # extract the request
      elif [ -z "$line" ] # empty line / end of request
      then
        # call a script here
        # Note: REQUEST is exported, so the script can parse it (to answer 200/403/404 status code + content)
        ./a_script.sh > out
      fi
    done
  )
done
```

And my a_script.sh (with your need):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo

date
```

Comment: After running the minimal_http_server.sh when we query the url multiple times within 1 second it displays page not found. But when we give an interval of 1 second for each request it works fine. Also noticed that when we keep this service running and have a curl request from another shell script the service goes down or crashes. Any idea what may be wrong

Comment: @satishjohn From my current skills (better than at the time), I have just corrected two major defects (`read` and `tr`) and a minor (`[` following elif).
I don't reproduce your problem. I don't see why the minimal_http_server.sh would cause these 1 second intervals.
You can determine whether it is minimal_http_server.sh or your "a_script.sh" that is faulty by running multiple times (at the same rate as your curl requests) ./a_script.sh after setting the REQUEST environment variable.

Answer (score 8):

```
mkfifo pipe;
while true ; 
do 
   #use read line from pipe to make it blocks before request comes in,
   #this is the key.
   { read line<pipe;echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";echo $(date);
   }  | nc -l -q 0 -p 8080 > pipe;  

done
```

Comment: how does it work? `read line<pipe` will wait until `nc` will write into `pipe`? But at this point, I would think the request is done before the response is written..?

Comment: mkfifo creates a blocking pipe, which means echo commands will not executed untill nc reads a request.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a beauty of [a little bash webserver](https://github.com/avleen/bashttpd), I found it online and forked a copy and spruced it up a bit - it uses `socat` or `netcat` I have tested it with `socat` -- it is self-contained in one-script and generates its own configuration file and favicon.

By default it will start up as a web enabled file browser yet is easily configured by the configuration file for any logic. For files it streams images and music (mp3's), video (mp4's, avi, etc) -- I have tested streaming various file types to Linux,Windows and Android devices including a smartwatch!

I think it streams better than VLC actually. I have found it useful for transferring files to remote clients who have no access beyond a web browser e.g. Android smartwatch without needing to worry about physically connecting to a USB port.

If you want to try it out just copy and paste it to a file named bashttpd, then start it up on the host with `$> bashttpd -s`

Then you can go to any other computer (presuming the firewall is not blocking inbound tcp connections to port 8080 -- the default port, you can change the port to whatever you want using the global variables at the top of the script). `http://bashttpd_server_ip:8080`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#############################################################################
###########################################################################
###                          bashttpd v 1.12
###
### Original author: Avleen Vig,       2012
### Reworked by:     Josh Cartwright,  2012
### Modified by:     A.M.Danischewski, 2015 
### Issues: If you find any issues leave me a comment at 
### http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2015/04/bashttpd-self-contained-bash-webserver.html 
### 
### This is a simple Bash based webserver. By default it will browse files and allows for 
### retrieving binary files. 
### 
### It has been tested successfully to view and stream files including images, mp3s, 
### mp4s and downloading files of any type including binary and compressed files via  
### any web browser. 
### 
### Successfully tested on various browsers on Windows, Linux and Android devices (including the 
### Android Smartwatch ZGPAX S8).  
### 
### It handles favicon requests by hardcoded favicon image -- by default a marathon 
### runner; change it to whatever you want! By base64 encoding your favorit favicon 
### and changing the global variable below this header.  
### 
### Make sure if you have a firewall it allows connections to the port you plan to 
### listen on (8080 by default).  
### 
### By default this program will allow for the browsing of files from the 
### computer where it is run.  
###  
### Make sure you are allowed connections to the port you plan to listen on 
### (8080 by default). Then just drop it on a host machine (that has bash) 
### and start it up like this:
###      
### $192.168.1.101> bashttpd -s
###      
### On the remote machine you should be able to browse and download files from the host 
### server via any web browser by visiting:
###      
### http://192.168.1.101:8080 
###  
#### This program requires (to work to full capacity) by default: 
### socat or netcat (w/ '-e' option - on Ubuntu netcat-traditional)
### tree - useful for pretty directory listings 
### If you are using socat, you can type: bashttpd -s  
### 
### to start listening on the LISTEN_PORT (default is 8080), you can change 
### the port below.  
###  E.g.    nc -lp 8080 -e ./bashttpd ## <-- If your nc has the -e option.   
###  E.g.    nc.traditional -lp 8080 -e ./bashttpd 
###  E.g.    bashttpd -s  -or- socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork EXEC:bashttpd
### 
### Copyright (C) 2012, Avleen Vig <avleen@gmail.com>
### 
### Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
### this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
### the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
### use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
### the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
### subject to the following conditions:
### 
### The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
### copies or substantial portions of the Software.
### 
### THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
### IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
### FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
### COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
### IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
### CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
### 
###########################################################################
#############################################################################

  ### CHANGE THIS TO WHERE YOU WANT THE CONFIGURATION FILE TO RESIDE 
declare -r BASHTTPD_CONF="/tmp/bashttpd.conf"

  ### CHANGE THIS IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO LISTEN ON A DIFFERENT PORT 
declare -i LISTEN_PORT=8080  

 ## If you are on AIX, IRIX, Solaris, or a hardened system redirecting 
 ## to /dev/random will probably break, you can change it to /dev/null.  
declare -a DUMP_DEV="/dev/random" 

 ## Just base64 encode your favorite favicon and change this to whatever you want.    
declare -r FAVICON="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" 

declare -i DEBUG=1 
declare -i VERBOSE=0
declare -a REQUEST_HEADERS
declare    REQUEST_URI="" 
declare -a HTTP_RESPONSE=(
   [200]="OK"
   [400]="Bad Request"
   [403]="Forbidden"
   [404]="Not Found"
   [405]="Method Not Allowed"
   [500]="Internal Server Error")
declare DATE=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
declare -a RESPONSE_HEADERS=(
      "Date: $DATE"
   "Expires: $DATE"
    "Server: Slash Bin Slash Bash"
)

function warn() { ((${VERBOSE})) && echo "WARNING: $@" >&2; }

function chk_conf_file() { 
[ -r "${BASHTTPD_CONF}" ] || {
   cat >"${BASHTTPD_CONF}" <<'EOF'
#
# bashttpd.conf - configuration for bashttpd
#
# The behavior of bashttpd is dictated by the evaluation
# of rules specified in this configuration file.  Each rule
# is evaluated until one is matched.  If no rule is matched,
# bashttpd will serve a 500 Internal Server Error.
#
# The format of the rules are:
#    on_uri_match REGEX command [args]
#    unconditionally command [args]
#
# on_uri_match:
#   On an incoming request, the URI is checked against the specified
#   (bash-supported extended) regular expression, and if encounters a match the
#   specified command is executed with the specified arguments.
#
#   For additional flexibility, on_uri_match will also pass the results of the
#   regular expression match, ${BASH_REMATCH[@]} as additional arguments to the
#   command.
#
# unconditionally:
#   Always serve via the specified command.  Useful for catchall rules.
#
# The following commands are available for use:
#
#   serve_file FILE
#     Statically serves a single file.
#
#   serve_dir_with_tree DIRECTORY
#     Statically serves the specified directory using 'tree'.  It must be
#     installed and in the PATH.
#
#   serve_dir_with_ls DIRECTORY
#     Statically serves the specified directory using 'ls -al'.
#
#   serve_dir  DIRECTORY
#     Statically serves a single directory listing.  Will use 'tree' if it is
#     installed and in the PATH, otherwise, 'ls -al'
#
#   serve_dir_or_file_from DIRECTORY
#     Serves either a directory listing (using serve_dir) or a file (using
#     serve_file).  Constructs local path by appending the specified root
#     directory, and the URI portion of the client request.
#
#   serve_static_string STRING
#     Serves the specified static string with Content-Type text/plain.
#
# Examples of rules:
#
# on_uri_match '^/issue$' serve_file "/etc/issue"
#
#   When a client's requested URI matches the string '/issue', serve them the
#   contents of /etc/issue
#
# on_uri_match 'root' serve_dir /
#
#   When a client's requested URI has the word 'root' in it, serve up
#   a directory listing of /
#
# DOCROOT=/var/www/html
# on_uri_match '/(.*)' serve_dir_or_file_from "$DOCROOT"
#   When any URI request is made, attempt to serve a directory listing
#   or file content based on the request URI, by mapping URI's to local
#   paths relative to the specified "$DOCROOT"
#
#unconditionally serve_static_string 'Hello, world!  You can configure bashttpd by modifying bashttpd.conf.'
DOCROOT=/
on_uri_match '/(.*)' serve_dir_or_file_from 
# More about commands:
#
# It is possible to somewhat easily write your own commands.  An example
# may help.  The following example will serve "Hello, $x!" whenever
# a client sends a request with the URI /say_hello_to/$x:
#
# serve_hello() {
#    add_response_header "Content-Type" "text/plain"
#    send_response_ok_exit <<< "Hello, $2!"
# }
# on_uri_match '^/say_hello_to/(.*)$' serve_hello
#
# Like mentioned before, the contents of ${BASH_REMATCH[@]} are passed
# to your command, so its possible to use regular expression groups
# to pull out info.
#
# With this example, when the requested URI is /say_hello_to/Josh, serve_hello
# is invoked with the arguments '/say_hello_to/Josh' 'Josh',
# (${BASH_REMATCH[0]} is always the full match)
EOF
   warn "Created bashttpd.conf using defaults.  Please review and configure bashttpd.conf before running bashttpd again."
#  exit 1
} 
}

function recv() { ((${VERBOSE})) && echo "< $@" >&2; }

function send() { ((${VERBOSE})) && echo "> $@" >&2; echo "$*"; }

function add_response_header() { RESPONSE_HEADERS+=("$1: $2"); }

function send_response_binary() {
  local code="$1"
  local file="${2}" 
  local transfer_stats="" 
  local tmp_stat_file="/tmp/_send_response_$$_"
  send "HTTP/1.0 $1 ${HTTP_RESPONSE[$1]}"
  for i in "${RESPONSE_HEADERS[@]}"; do
     send "$i"
  done
  send
 if ((${VERBOSE})); then 
   ## Use dd since it handles null bytes
  dd 2>"${tmp_stat_file}" < "${file}" 
  transfer_stats=$(<"${tmp_stat_file}") 
  echo -en ">> Transferred: ${file}\n>> $(awk '/copied/{print}' <<< "${transfer_stats}")\n" >&2  
  rm "${tmp_stat_file}"
 else 
   ## Use dd since it handles null bytes
  dd 2>"${DUMP_DEV}" < "${file}"   
 fi 
}   

function send_response() {
  local code="$1"
  send "HTTP/1.0 $1 ${HTTP_RESPONSE[$1]}"
  for i in "${RESPONSE_HEADERS[@]}"; do
     send "$i"
  done
  send
  while IFS= read -r line; do
     send "${line}"
  done
}

function send_response_ok_exit() { send_response 200; exit 0; }

function send_response_ok_exit_binary() { send_response_binary 200  "${1}"; exit 0; }

function fail_with() { send_response "$1" <<< "$1 ${HTTP_RESPONSE[$1]}"; exit 1; }

function serve_file() {
  local file="$1"
  local CONTENT_TYPE=""
  case "${file}" in
    *\.css)
      CONTENT_TYPE="text/css"
      ;;
    *\.js)
      CONTENT_TYPE="text/javascript"
      ;;
    *)
      CONTENT_TYPE=$(file -b --mime-type "${file}")
      ;;
  esac
  add_response_header "Content-Type"  "${CONTENT_TYPE}"
  CONTENT_LENGTH=$(stat -c'%s' "${file}") 
  add_response_header "Content-Length" "${CONTENT_LENGTH}"
    ## Use binary safe transfer method since text doesn't break. 
  send_response_ok_exit_binary "${file}"
}

function serve_dir_with_tree() {
  local dir="$1" tree_vers tree_opts basehref x
    ## HTML 5 compatible way to avoid tree html from generating favicon
    ## requests in certain browsers, such as browsers in android smartwatches. =) 
  local no_favicon=" <link href=\"data:image/x-icon;base64,${FAVICON}\" rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />"  
  local tree_page="" 
  local base_server_path="/${2%/}"
  [ "$base_server_path" = "/" ] && base_server_path=".." 
  local tree_opts="--du -h -a --dirsfirst" 
  add_response_header "Content-Type" "text/html"
   # The --du option was added in 1.6.0.   "/${2%/*}"
  read _ tree_vers x < <(tree --version)
  tree_page=$(tree -H "$base_server_path" -L 1 "${tree_opts}" -D "${dir}")
  tree_page=$(sed "5 i ${no_favicon}" <<< "${tree_page}")  
  [[ "${tree_vers}" == v1.6* ]] 
  send_response_ok_exit <<< "${tree_page}"  
}

function serve_dir_with_ls() {
  local dir="$1"
  add_response_header "Content-Type" "text/plain"
  send_response_ok_exit < \
     <(ls -la "${dir}")
}

function serve_dir() {
  local dir="$1"
   # If `tree` is installed, use that for pretty output.
  which tree &>"${DUMP_DEV}" && \
     serve_dir_with_tree "$@"
  serve_dir_with_ls "$@"
  fail_with 500
}

function urldecode() { [ "${1%/}" = "" ] && echo "/" ||  echo -e "$(sed 's/%\([[:xdigit:]]\{2\}\)/\\\x\1/g' <<< "${1%/}")"; } 

function serve_dir_or_file_from() {
  local URL_PATH="${1}/${3}"
  shift
  URL_PATH=$(urldecode "${URL_PATH}") 
  [[ $URL_PATH == *..* ]] && fail_with 400
   # Serve index file if exists in requested directory
  [[ -d "${URL_PATH}" && -f "${URL_PATH}/index.html" && -r "${URL_PATH}/index.html" ]] && \
     URL_PATH="${URL_PATH}/index.html"
  if [[ -f "${URL_PATH}" ]]; then
     [[ -r "${URL_PATH}" ]] && \
        serve_file "${URL_PATH}" "$@" || fail_with 403
  elif [[ -d "${URL_PATH}" ]]; then
     [[ -x "${URL_PATH}" ]] && \
        serve_dir  "${URL_PATH}" "$@" || fail_with 403
  fi
  fail_with 404
}

function serve_static_string() {
  add_response_header "Content-Type" "text/plain"
  send_response_ok_exit <<< "$1"
}

function on_uri_match() {
  local regex="$1"
  shift
  [[ "${REQUEST_URI}" =~ $regex ]] && \
     "$@" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
}

function unconditionally() { "$@" "$REQUEST_URI"; }

function main() { 
  local recv="" 
  local line="" 
  local REQUEST_METHOD=""
  local REQUEST_HTTP_VERSION="" 
  chk_conf_file
  [[ ${UID} = 0 ]] && warn "It is not recommended to run bashttpd as root."
   # Request-Line HTTP RFC 2616 $5.1
  read -r line || fail_with 400
  line=${line%%$'\r'}
  recv "${line}"
  read -r REQUEST_METHOD REQUEST_URI REQUEST_HTTP_VERSION <<< "${line}"
  [ -n "${REQUEST_METHOD}" ] && [ -n "${REQUEST_URI}" ] && \
   [ -n "${REQUEST_HTTP_VERSION}" ] || fail_with 400
   # Only GET is supported at this time
  [ "${REQUEST_METHOD}" = "GET" ] || fail_with 405
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=${line%%$'\r'}
    recv "${line}"
      # If we've reached the end of the headers, break.
    [ -z "${line}" ] && break
    REQUEST_HEADERS+=("${line}")
  done
} 

if [[ ! -z "{$1}" ]] && [ "${1}" = "-s" ]; then 
 socat TCP4-LISTEN:${LISTEN_PORT},fork EXEC:"${0}" 
else 
 main 
 source "${BASHTTPD_CONF}" 
 fail_with 500
fi
```

Comment: How would you modify this to accept POST as well as GET?

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk You would have to add logic to handle Post requests (not that hard), here is a link to the latest source code, look in the `main` function where it says `[ "${REQUEST_METHOD}" = "GET" ] || fail_with 405`: https://github.com/AdamDanischewski/bashttpd/blob/master/bashttpd

Answer (score 6):

LOL, a super lame hack, but at least curl and firefox accepts it:

```
while true ; do (dd if=/dev/zero count=10000;echo -e "HTTP/1.1\n\n $(date)") | nc -l  1500  ; done
```

You better replace it soon with something proper!

Ah yes, my `nc` were not exactly the same as yours, it did not like the `-p` option.

Comment: This answer works with netcat on OS X 10.10.1. Super awesome!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Apline Linux, the BusyBox netcat is slightly different:

```
while true; do nc -l -p 8080 -e sh -c 'echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n$(date)"'; done
```

And another way using `printf`:

```
while true; do nc -l -p 8080 -e sh -c "printf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n%s' \"$(date)\""; done
```

Comment: `echo -e` is not reliable, especially with `sh`. A strictly POSIX-compliant `echo` will treat `-e` as data to write to stdout, not a flag that modifies its behavior; use `printf` instead to get reliable results: `printf '%s\n' 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' '' "$(date)"`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the best way to close gracefully the connection is to send the `Content-Length` header like following. Client (like `curl` will close the connection after receiving the data.

```sh
DATA="Date: $(date)"; 
LENGTH=$(echo $DATA | wc -c);
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Length: ${LENGTH}\n\n${DATA}" | nc -l -p 8000;
```

Comment: `echo $DATA | wc -c` is not necessarily the same length as `"$DATA"`: When you put it outside quotes in the echo, you make wildcards be expanded, runs of whitespace be changed to single spaces, etc. Use `length=${#data}` instead (using lower-case variable names per [POSIX-specified convention](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html); read that document keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace).

Answer (score 4):

```
while true; do (echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n';) | timeout 1  nc -lp 8080 ; done
```

Closes connection after 1 sec, so curl doesn't hang on it.

Comment: My bash shell hung after I tried this. Ctrl+Z didn't kill the process. I had to spawn another shell instance and delete the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Type in *nc -h* and see if You have *-e* option available. If yes, You can create a script, for example:

*script.sh*

```
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)"
```

and run it like this:

```
while true ; do nc -l -p 1500 -e script.sh; done
```

Note that *-e* option needs to be enabled at compilation to be available.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem that all the solution listed doesn't work, is intrinsic in the nature of http service, the every request established is with a different client and the response need to be processed in a different context, every request must fork a new instance of response...

The current solution I think is the `-e` of `netcat` but I don't know why doesn't work... maybe is my `nc` version that I test on `openwrt`...

with `socat` it works....

I try this https://github.com/avleen/bashttpd

and it works, but I must run the shell script with this command.

```
socat tcp-l:80,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:bashttpd &
```

The `socat` and `netcat` samples on github doesn't works for me, but the `socat` that I used works.

Comment: with `reuseaddr` flag you made my day!  THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you can use :

```
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l  localhost 1500 ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to the party, but I usually like to avoid `while true` loops in bash and `ncat` has two convenient flags for this:

- `-k` (or `--keep-open`)
- `-c` (or `--sh-exec`)

So I would do this one-liner:

```bash
ncat -l localhost 1500 -k -c "printf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n%s\n' '$(date)'"
```

Be aware of your `ncat` version, as the `nc` for OSX is slightly different. I used:

```
Ncat: Version 7.94 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```

Answer (score 0):

You typically need more than just `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` in the response header, otherwise the HTTP client waits for more response data. The command below seems to do the job:

```
while true ; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"\
                        "Date: $(date)\n"\
                        "Server: Echo\n"\
                        "Content-Length: 0\n"\
                        "Connection: Closed\n"\
                | nc -l localhost 1500; done
```