# Can bash be used to create a server?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to program a server in bash?

Basically I want be able to connect to a bash server from a PHP client and send messages that will be displayed in console.

Comment: Bash itself does not have any socket or network capability. You have to use other programs to handle the network bits. One such program could be e.g. [netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/). You might also want to read e.g. [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16640054/440558).

Comment: `wall` may do what you want too.

Comment: @Mat I don't want to connect with PHP server - PHP is my client, and Bash - my server.

Answer (score 2):

**The bad news first**

Unfortunately, there seems to be no hope to do this in **pure** Bash.

Even doing a

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/<ip>/<port>
```

does not work, because these special files are implemented on top on `connect()` instead of `bind()`.  This is apparent if we look at the source.

In Bash 4.2, for example, the function `_netopen4()` (or `_netopen6()` for IPv6) reads as follows (`lib/sh/netopen.c`):

```
  s = socket(AF_INET, (typ == 't') ? SOCK_STREAM : SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (s < 0)
    {
      sys_error ("socket");
      return (-1);
    }

  if (connect (s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof (sin)) < 0)
    {
      e = errno;
      sys_error("connect");
      close(s);
      errno = e;
      return (-1);
    }
```

**But**

It is possible to use a command line tool such as `nc`.  E.g.,

```
nc -l <port>
```

will listen for incoming connections on `localhost:<port>`.

Comment: and to redirect the text from php client to display on console use
`nc -l port > \`tty\``

Answer (score 2):

Create a process that reads from a socket, executes the data via shell, and prints back the response. Possible with the following script, which listens on port 9213:

```
ncat -l -kp 9213 | while read line; do
    out=$($line)
    # or echo $line
    echo $out
done
```

If all you want is to display the data, `ncat -l -p 9213` is sufficient though.

Comment: This is not pure bash, however.

Comment: I don't see any reference to pureness in the OP.

Comment: But - he says **in Bash**.

Comment: well everything happens in bash, whatever.

Comment: I think bash script is nothing but every tool at disposal weaved in logic

Comment: Okay, I used your code in script and it worked - but when I connect to it using PHP it does not echo message that I send to it, and it is stopping after successful connection.

Comment: @shooly, to accept multiple connection add the `-k` option to netcat, updated above.

Comment: @shooly, just do `ncat -l -kp 9213` on a terminal and it should print stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project on GIT which implements a HTTP web server fully written in bash;

https://github.com/avleen/bashttpd