# Run python script from the web in a Raspberry Pi web server

Tags: php, python, webserver, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that picks an URL as parameter and it fetch some data (normally it takes 30 seconds to finish) and creates a file with it. What I want is to be able to call the script from a web (I thought about doing it with PHP but i don't mind) and just get the file path (which is printed at the begining of the script process) and leave the script running in background.

how can i do this? which is the best way?

Note: I'm using a raspberry pi as a web server and the python file is located in /var/www/

Comment: Use a web framework such as bottle or flask. They are very light and quick to develop something simple like this.

Comment: go Here browse the website you will find what you are looking for http://hackaholic.info/category/raspberry-pi/

Comment: you could do you own "webserver" like that return a script...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat/21204114#21204114

Answer (score 0):

php can execute system commands using the command `system()`.

To execute a python script, you can use this command:

```
system('/path/to/python /path/to/test.py');
```

To leave it running in the background, use `&`:

```
system('/path/to/python /path/to/test.py &');
```

If you want to start the script in the background but still get the first lines of output, I would redirect the output to a file:

```
system('/path/to/python /path/to/test.py >/var/www/unique_file.txt &');
sleep(500); // Script has printed the file path now
$output = file_get_contents("unique_file.txt");
```