# Access Raspberry Pie over Internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I have succeeded to stream webcam video over a local network using Raspberry Pie but now I want to access this stream from the Internet. Can someone please help me to point in right direction? I am just not able to understand how can I access Raspberry Pie from Internet.

I also want to send a commands to Raspberry Pie from the server to enable Raspberry Pie carry out some specific operations like RESET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try this - https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/ (scroll to the end).

Still I am not sure if I will be able to send commands to Raspberry Pie from the server.

[EDIT]

RPie will be pushing data to the server and checking status regular interval if there's anything to Run!

[EDIT]

I cannot use port forwarding method given at https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/ so basically I am still left with open question!

Comment: what do you mean by server, what kind of server? what is the server doing? have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat/21204114#21204114) to get info from the pi with websockets you can do bidirectional comm if not you have to implement something with html/forms or something like that, that implement like a button on a web to restart for example, also [webiopi ](http://webiopi.trouch.com/) if you want to send pin status...

Comment: Server is Wowza cloud instance. I am still not able to do it as I don't want to do port forwarding. Not sure if there is any direct way to stream NVR to Wowza!

Comment: I suggest you contact their support team. unless there is a way to connect the stream directly to the cloud instance, which is highly unlikely you will have to do port forwarding if you need so you are goin to need some kind of  DDNS service in any unless you have public static IP.

Comment: check this out: https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?33490-Raspberry-PI https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=30801&p=307439

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send command to Raspberry Pi over internet, in my case I setup a RESTful Application in Pi.

Setup a RESTful web application using Flask. e.g http:///reset
then implement your logic in the reset.