# Curl as REST server

Tags: linux, rest, curl

I know that I can make a REST client using curl like this

```
curl -o out.json http://www.example.com/index.html
```

Is there a way to make a rest server that send a json file using command line?

i.e. a server listening to curl requests and respond with a json data.

Thanks.

Comment: curl is a client-side application to make requests, it only listens for the response to its own request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider [Python's SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) that can be run with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]`, with default http being port 80. All you need to do is store a JSON file in the directory where you run the command, and you can access the url to the JSON file with `http://127.0.0.1/path/to/file.json`. Alternatively, you could check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat) for a method to make a simple web server with netcat. However, curl is a client-side application and can't be used to create a web server.