One liner HTTP server responding in JSON?
There are times when I want to just launch a quick http server on a basic linux machine with no special software installed.
I run the following:
python3 -m http.server 8080

This returns the directory listing HTML page with response code 200.
Is there a similar one-liner that can return {"OK"} or some basic json?
It doesn't have to be python.

Just an example: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

This returns the directory listing HTML page with response code 200. -- actually it starts serving the current directory. So if you have a my.json file there, with {"OK"} inside, http://localhost:8080/my.json will return it. That's not a valid JSON, by the way.

With netcat maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139134/2836621

You might customize http.server though to get desired result few lines are required. Create myserver.py file holding
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'{"response":"OK"}')

HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), GetHandler).serve_forever()

then
python3 myserver.py

will start server at port 8000 of localhost responding with {"response":"OK"} with any GET request.
